# How to split the column and merge them into one row(or one column) using power query?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

There is one column with several rows which I want to convert into one column after split.
Each cell of the column contains several values which can be split based on commas as separator.
But I feel a bit confused about what to do next after separation.
Could anyone help me with this?
Please take a look at the picture shown below.

**This is the table which I want to convert**

[image: This is the table which I want to convert]

**The end result of the table**

[image: The end result of the table]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the range of you data, click Data > From Table/Range. If your range/table has headers, tick "My table has headers"
2. When the Power Query Editor opens, on the Home or Transform tab, click Split Column > By Delimiter.
3. Select the delimiter in you case Comma.
4. Set Split at to "Each occurrence of the delimiter".
5. Click Advanced options, set Split into to Rows.
6. Set Quote Character to None.  See image below for reference to set Split Column by delimiter options.

[image: IMG:]

7. Click OK. Your rows will be split based on the selected delimiter.

[image: IMG:]

8. On the Transform tab, click Format > Trim to remove leading or trailing spaces as suggested by @RonRosenfeld on the comments.

[image: IMG:]

8. Click Close & Load. The image below shows the final result.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thanks for your instruction. It works!
But now I have one problem encountered, which leads to the disappearance of "."(dot).
After the split, the value followed by "." disappear and I couldn't find it through filter.
Any solution to get around this?

Comment: @JohnHuang What do you mean by the disappearance of dot? Your sample data on the OP did not have dots. Are there dots in some cells?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Suggest you `Trim` before `Close & Load`. There are some leading spaces in the split data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Good suggestion. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio 
Sorry for the late reply. I didn't show the real data I am dealing with in the sample data set for the sake of simplicity. For example, 122.,122,158.,A122.......
As you can see from above, there are some numbers followed by "."  and these "dot" disappear after the split.

Comment: I have put dot for some numbers, they are not removed. Check if the dot is considered as a comma on your machine settings.